# CREATE LOGIN is not recognised by a trigger it password is empty

Tags: sql-server

Accordingly to company policy I have to prevent creating SQL logins with CHECK_POLICY=OFF setting, so I've created a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [create_or_alter_login] ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_LOGIN, ALTER_LOGIN
as
begin
    DECLARE @data xml
    DECLARE @text nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @user nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @object_name nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @MESSAGE_LOG varchar(255);
    DECLARE @MESSAGE_PRINT varchar(255);
    
    SET @data = EVENTDATA();
    SET @text = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    SET @user = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    SET @object_name = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    IF(@text LIKE N'%CHECK_POLICY=OFF%')
    BEGIN
        SET @MESSAGE_LOG = 'CHECK_POLICY=OFF is a forbidden setting. Rollback for a batch ' + @text 
        exec xp_logevent 60000, @MESSAGE_LOG , warning
        SET @MESSAGE_PRINT  = '
        ************************************************************
        ' + 'CHECK_POLICY=OFF is a forbidden setting.
        ' + 'Rollback SQL login change for '+ @object_name + '
        ************************************************************
        '
        Rollback
        RAISERROR (@MESSAGE_PRINT,10,1)
        
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @MESSAGE_LOG = 'SQL Login has been created or changed: ' + @text
        exec xp_logevent 60000, @MESSAGE_LOG , informational
    END
END
```

In case of
`CREATE LOGIN [test7] WITH PASSWORD=N'there is a password', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF`
trigger is functioning and blocks creating a login with CHECK_POLICY=OFF (script and GUI)

In case of empty password:
`CREATE LOGIN [test7] WITH PASSWORD=N'', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF`
login is created and it doesn't matter if I use t-sql or GUI.

Any idea what happens where and how I should modify a trigger to prevent creating a login with CHECK_POLICY=OFF and empty password?

Tested on SQL 2012, 2016, 2017 and 2019

Thank you!

Comment: You are missing an `END` in the `CREATE TRIGGER` code block

Comment: @Zikato, thank you, it was copy-paste error in a question, I've fixed it. Trigger is functioniing properly if password is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I altered the trigger so that it prints the content of `EVENTDATA()`. In case of a `CREATE LOGIN` with a password, the event data contains the whole statement (under TSQLCommand/CommandText). In case there is an empty password, the event CommandText only contains `--*CREATE LOGIN-----------------------------------------`. Since the trigger checks the CommandText, which in this case contains only some kind of placeholder, it would not match.

Comment: Thank you, I've just double-checked it using profiler and extended events. It seems Microsoft has created a "feature" where. Event StmtStarting gives a message:
```-- 'CREATE LOGIN' was found in the text of this event.
-- The text has been replaced with this comment for security reasons.  ``` 
So I can prefent a Loging with password AND a setting, but not the worse  version of it which use NO password and bad setting. Excellent job, Microsoft.

Comment: I agree @Mainecoon21. One option you have is to also filter for the `--*CREATE LOGIN--` which basically means login without password and prevent that as well.

Comment: @Zikato, yes, and than I've also to check the behavior of ALTER LOGIN, because it's also should be not possible to remove the setting later on.